# Google sheet + Web app search specific column and return all matching rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webapp2

Anybody knows how can I amend the code below to only search from a specific column in Google sheet e.g. column J?

The code below works great and returns the entire row that matches the searchtext, but the search is across the entire range within the google sheet.
https://www.bpwebs.com/create-web-forms-to-get-data-from-google-sheets/comment-page-1/#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const colIndex = 9; // Column J
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (f[colIndex] == searchtext) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
```

Comment: When i change it to this, it only returns column J. I need it to return column A:N, but only search column J.

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. :) Would you happen to know if its possible to sum up column N and display it below or something? In column N each row has a $$ value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'display it below' and a '$$' value? Please create a new question and elaborate.